# Log in with Facebook in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, authentication, sql-server-2012

I have a project for creating a summer reading program registration tool (in ASP.NET c#) for a local library.

They require me to develop a "log in with Facebook" and "log in with Google" button that will take care of the account creation process. However, I am new to ASP.NET and do not know where to begin with this process!

All I can find on the Facebook developer page is the Javascript SDK, but my application will be built in C#, so can I still use that SDK? Also, I am trying to figure out how to build my database, so that one account (linked to Facebook/Google) can register multiple "children" in the reading program.

Does anyone know any good resources for where I can start?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Assuming that you are using ASP .NET MVC, this is a good guide: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC 5 and new WebForms (as of 2013 VS Update 3, 2013 Express works too) support all kind of authentication

In visual studio 2013

1. go to File = New Project Visual C# => ASP.nET Web Application and choose ASP.NET MVC or WebForms. This will give you a template ready to start-setting up for Facebook, Google, MicrosoftAcc, twitter, OAuth. This "Start template" will also give you a good base to start your project.
2. Inside Startup.Auth.cs you can specify your AppIds for facebook/google etc
3. Read about details : http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#auth

3b. (for WebForms) http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#auth

Comment: Thanks, I just created an ASP.NET Empty Website and not project. Do you recommend me creating a project instead? The idea is that I will hand this off to the local Library, and they will host the tool on the City's Website.

If I chose to develop the tool in a Web site, would it still be possible to use the "log in with Facebbok" button?

Comment: Is this going to be a new website or you will be developing new login options for existing one?

Comment: this will be a new page (accessible through a new tab) on the City's Website. Currently, no login options exist. (The reason I chose to create an Empty Website is because that's how I learned to code in ASP.NET)

Comment: I am not sure if empty website will teach you anything. Did you try one these templates ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET WebForms? In ASP you have 3 ways to create a dynamic website 1. Just using ASP.NET WebPage or Using one of these Frameworks "ASP.NET Web Forms" or "ASP.NET MVC". If you create a template project with WebForms/MVC you will get a fully working example website which alreay handles login, database connections etc, Alternative is to do everything from scratch instead of understanding how MVC or WebForm works. Anyhow here is where you start http://www.asp.net/get-started/websites#web-pages

Comment: Handling login is about showing a form to the user, or a button where he connects/logins to facebook or google. Then grabbing these session states and storing in a database, either a local one or connect to real SQL Server. It feels like you need to learn quite a lot before you can actually create your login page. Here is another good video on how to start with asp.net mvc http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/introduction-to-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Thanks for your reply,the City has let me know that they want me to hand off the project in a new Website format. It's really odd I cannot find much for Websites online that uses the login with Facebook button